# setAutoHeight() gxt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am creating a ContentPanel with BorderLayouts in gxt.
Need to set auto width and height for panel. setAutowidth() works properly but setAutoHeight() doesn't.

So, what should I implement to make my ContentPanel autoHeighed?

Comment: Found a post with such words: "dont use setAutoHeight() with BorderLayout"

Comment: Why? When I create a simple FOrmPanel without layouts setAutoHeight and setAutoWidth work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 
container.setHeight("auto"); 
It worked for me.

There is another option. You can also try this

container.setStyleAttribute("height","auto !important");
container.setStyleAttribute("overflow","visible !important");

Comment: When I use TabPanel I setAutoHeight(true) to tabPanel, but I shouldn't use it - the height becomes minus. The better way is to use setAutoheight to tabpanel's childs